# Finding $f=f'=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f\left(x\right)=e^{-x^2}\left(1-ax^2\right)+1$. Find the value of $a$ such that $f\left(x_0\right)=f'\left(x_0\right)=0$.

This is a problem that came to me while analyzing the graph of the function; I've tried several algebraic methods to find a solution but so far haven't had any luck. Through graphical analysis I've found that $a\approx3.6$, but if there is either a way to obtain a precise solution or a more accurate approximation I would prefer that.

Attempt:
$$f'\left(x\right)=2xe^{-x^2}\left(ax^2-a-1\right)$$
$$0=2xe^{-x^2}\left(ax^2-a-1\right)=ax^2-a-1$$
$$a=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$$

$$0=e^{-x^2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}\right)+1$$
$$e^{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$$
From here I'm not sure how to find a solution. My idea was to solve for the zeroes of the function and then plug them back into the equation for $a$ to find its value.

Comment: By the way, $W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\approx 0.27846454276107379511$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have
$$f(x)=e^{-x^2} \left(1-a x^2\right)+1\tag 1$$
$$f'(x)=2 e^{-x^2} x \left(a \left(x^2-1\right)-1\right)\tag 2$$ Assuming $x\neq 0$, as you did, this reduces to
$$a \left(x^2-1\right)-1=0\implies x^2=1+\frac 1 a$$ Replace in $(1)$ to get
$$f\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{a}}\right)=1-a e^{-(1+\frac{1}{a})}$$ and the solution of $1=a e^{-(1+\frac{1}{a})}$ is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$a=\frac{1}{W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)}\approx 3.59112 \implies x^2=1+W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\approx 1.27846$$

Answer (score 0):

From $f'(x_0)=0$ we get $x_0=0$ or $1-ax_0^2=-a$. Since $f(0) \ne 0$ we have $1-ax_0^2=-a$, hence

$0=f(x_0)=e^{-x_0^2}(-a)+1=0$. This gives $e^{x_0^2}=a$, thus $a>1$ and $x_0^2= \ln a$.